# Visual Studio 2017 Remote Build for Linux with Boost

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, boost, build

I have a C++ project which uses "boost/asio.hpp". On my Linux machine, I can build that project with CMake.

However, when I set it up with Visual Studio 2017 on my Windows machine, even though I added "boost_asio" to Properties/Linker/Input, I still have the error: "fatal error: boost/asio.hpp: no such file or directory." I also tried to add the boost path on my Windows machine to the "Additional Library Directories" but it still did not work.

I don't think I understand how the compilation process in this case is.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you are trying to build a Windows application and you have installed and built the **boost** libraries on your Windows system:

In project properties under `C/C++` add `<the path to your boost root folder>` to `Additional Include Directories`, e.g. `c:\boost_1_65_1` .

`boost::asio` is a header-only library so this is all you need to do.

However some **boost** libraries have object libraries that you must link to, in which case:

In project properties under `Linker/General` add `<the path to your boost root folder>\stage\lib` to `Additional Library Directories`, e.g. `c:\boost_1_65_1\stage\lib` . On Windows, **boost** will add the reference to the object library automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I'm building a Linux application using Visual Studio in Windows environment. I have a Linux remote machine which my VS connects to in order to build.

Comment: In that case you should set `Additional Include Directories` in `C/C++` to the path to your boost root folder on the Linux remote. Use the absolute path (i.e. not relative). And, if you want IntelliSense to recognise the asio functions etc. install boost on your Windows host as well and include the path to the boost root on Windows in `Additional Include Directories`. Ie. you will specify the path to the asio headers *twice*, once for Windows, once for Linux.